# Can we use 'bg' to get get only the changes n data of two CSV in Google Cloud storage bucket for Optimization?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, query-optimization, bq

cat compare_data_gse_query.sql | bq query --use_legacy_sql=False

(1) Cost optimization in GSP. lots of the SQL query do need the changes.
(2) How to compare CSV data (today | yesterday) changes in GSC - Google Storage

(3) SQL * is to to be avoided. is there any utility in 'bq' CLI could handle ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: MERGE dataset.target T
USING dataset.source S
ON T.COLUMN_ID = S.COLUMN_ID
WHEN MATCHED AND T._PARTITIONTIME = '2018-01-01' THEN
  UPDATE SET COLUMN_ID = S.COLUMN_ID
WHEN MATCHED AND T._PARTITIONTIME = '2018-01-02' THEN
  UPDATE SET COLUMN_ID = S.COLUMN_ID + 10
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND T._PARTITIONTIME = '2018-01-03' THEN
  DELETE